# Do you want the application "WebStorm.app" to accept incoming network connections?

Tags: macos, webstorm, osx-yosemite, jetbrains-ide

Webstorm keeps asking to accept incoming network connections on Mac OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 1):

I had to create my own certificate on Keychain Access then 'codesign' Webstorm via terminal.

1. Open Keychain Access (Applications/Utilities)
2. Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Create a Certificate
3. Add 'your certificate name' > Identity Type 'Self Signed Root' > Certificate Type 'Code Signing'
4. Open Terminal

   $ sudo codesign -s "your certificate name" -f /Applications/WebStorm.app/
5. Restart computer (not always)
6. Open WebStorm.app
7. Accept incoming network connections for the last time

The same process should work for any JetBrains IDE e.g. PhpStorm, PyCharm, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Such errors usually indicate broken application signature. They may occur after changing info.plist or other files in WebStorm installation directory

Comment: Thanks Lena. The error occurs on WS 10.0.4 installation on a brand new OS X Yosemite instance. I assume it must be a know issue but nothing major. I provided a work around fix that seems to work fine in all the machines across our team. Cheers